# Adding a class to <tr> if <a> element has text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to a add a class to every  element that contains an `<a>` with a text so I could hide the `<tr>`'s that has no text! here is my HTML code and JavaScript:

```js
$("tr a").each(function () {
    var a= $(e);
    if ($e.text().length > 0) {
        tr.addClass("buttoneffect");
    }
});
```

```css
table tr {
    height: 36px;
}

table tr:hover {
    background-color: #BEDB7F;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="">Test 1</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="">Test 2</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href=""></a></td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="">Test 4</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="">Test 6</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what is $(e)? then in your if statement if you $e. Which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/s1h1p1ua/1/)

first you are referencing `e` , which you didn't pass inside the event callback, and there is no `tr` directly accessible you have to find out the `closest` `tr` to that of `a`

```
$("tr a").each(function () {
    var a= $(this);
    if (a.text().length > 0) {
        a.closest('tr').addClass("buttoneffect");
    }
});
```

---

Also if you want the trs to be hidden, you can add css for that: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/s1h1p1ua/2/)

```
tr:not(.buttoneffect)
{
    display:none;
}
```

```js
$("tr a").each(function() {
  var a = $(this);
  if (a.text().length > 0) {
    a.closest('tr').addClass("buttoneffect");
  }
});
```

```css
table tr {
  height: 36px;
}
table tr:hover {
  background-color: #BEDB7F;
}
.buttoneffect {
  background: red;
}
tr:not(.buttoneffect) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="">Test 1</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="">Test 2</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href=""></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="">Test 4</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href=""></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="">Test 6</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .filter() find filter those elements and then call .addClass() on the filtered set to add the class

```
$("tr").filter(function () {
    return $(this).find('a').text().trim().length > 0
}).addClass("buttoneffect");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/57vxhx29/)

Answer (score 0):

use jquery parent().

```
$("tr a").each(function () {
   var a= $(this);
   if (a.text().length > 0) {
         a.parnt('tr').addClass("buttoneffect");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ts6xgqaa/2/)

```
$("tr a").each(function () {
    var a= $(this);
    if (a.text().length > 0) {
        a.closest('tr').addClass("buttoneffect");
    }
});
```